# Core Data pre-fetching and KVO compliance

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I'm having a problem with KVO exceptions being thrown if I attempt to prefetch related entities in Core Data.  It doesn't make any sense to me and I can't seem to duplicate the behavior in a simplified project.  I'm targeting 10.8 and using ARC.

My data models a music library and I have three entities of interest: `Track`, `Artist`, and `Album`.  A track has a single artist and a single album, while an album has a single artist.  My `Album` and `Artist` objects are uniqued by name (only one artist with a given name in the store).

I want to display a list of tracks with the following fields: title, artist.name, album.title.  This is easily accomplished using an NSArrayController for the `Track` entity and bindings in an NSTableView.

However, since I know that I will be using the artist and album relationships I would like to prefetch them when the tracks are loaded.  I created an NSArrayController subclass with a custom performFetch: method that looks like this:

```
- (BOOL) fetchWithRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest merge:(BOOL)merge error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [Track entityInManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];
    [fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[@"album", @"artist"]];

    return [super fetchWithRequest:fetchRequest merge:merge error:error];
}
```

I set the NSArrayController's class in IB to my subclass and I expected that the UI lag would disappear (faults were firing with each scroll).  However, an exception is thrown:

> 2013-01-01 10:48:06.965 XXX[10593:303] Cannot update for
>   observer  for the key path "artist.name"
>   from , most likely because the value for the key
>   "artist" has changed without an appropriate KVO notification being
>   sent. Check the KVO-compliance of the Track class.

Before the custom `NSArrayController` subclass everything worked correctly.  By simply commenting out the `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching` line in my `NSArrayController` subclass everything works again.  I can't determine what the link is between prefetching and KVO.  Have any Core Data experts seen something like this before?

Comment: Are you calling `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` somewhere?

Comment: No, I don't make any manual KVC calls.  I'm using Core Data's synthesized setters/getters in my `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

Comment: This seems to be an Apple bug and also happens with NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into essentially the same problem, and this is what I learned while resolving it:

It seems that NSArrayController does not play nicely with `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:` in all situations. I was executing a prefetching request in a child context and this ended up breaking KVC for an `NSArrayController` in the parent context, which I imagine to be unintended behavior. In any case, the way I fixed it was to use the ["old" style (10.4) prefetching](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW6), which would look something like...

```
NSFetchRequest *trackReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Track"];
NSArray *fetchedTracks = [context executeFetchRequest:trackReq error:&error];

NSFetchRequest *batchFaultReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Artist"];
[batchFaultReq setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.tracks in %@", fetchedTracks];
NSArray *faultedItems = [context executeFetchRequest:batchFaultReq error:&error];

// do something with fetchedTracks
```

... how you plug this into your `NSArrayController` subclass is another matter - it's not immediately clear to me how to use this method within a `fetchWithRequest:` override since you need the fetched results before you can execute the batch faulting request. On a side note, you've experimented with the lazy fetching flag?

Comment: I ended up overriding `-defaultFetchRequest` to do basically the same fetch request as I outlined above and things worked properly.